# UrbanCode Deploy - Mapping Component to Agent on-the-fly

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, ucd

From what I can tell after reading IBM documentation is that, after creating a component in UCD, you'd have to manually map that component to an available Resource/Agents that you had already setup.

The way I have my pipeline setup is that, my Jenkins job is the one that's creating components. So in other words, on UCD, I have the application, environment, agents, etc... all that set up, but no components are created -- because my Jenkins job (it's really a Jenkinsfile) is the one that's creating components.

But in order to do a successful deployment, one of the things you have to do is map this component to an Agent. **I don't want to have to log back into UCD to manually map this recently created component to one of the available Agents**.

When Jenkins is creating the components, it's referring to an already-defined Component Template in UCD to create the components. In the Component Template, I can specify a Component Process. I'm suspecting that in this process, I can specify a step to map the current component to an Agent, but I'm not able to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found the answer - you can set a component tag during jenkins deploy job (you can pass these properties as a parameter).

You can setup component tags in agents. If the value of the component tag in agent matches with the tag in the component, that component can be deployed to a VM using that agent with the matching component-tag.